# Angular get values in string that match a regex

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I have the following regex defined:

```
const regEx = new RegExp('[A][A-Z]{2}[0-2]{5}\b', 'g')
```

I have tested it in online regex testers and they all seem to work. I would like to search through a string for all words that look like this: `ADB12210`. They have to start with an A followed by 2 upper case letters and end with 5 numbers from 0-2 and be a global search since this could appear multiple times in the string. This seems to work but when I try it by creating a pipe in angular it doesn't find any matches. The match returns null but I am expecting an array like: `['ADB12210', 'ACG12212']`. My pipe is as follows:

```
transform(value: string): any {
  const regExp = new RegExp('[A][A-Z]{2}[0-2]{5}\b', 'g')
  console.log(value.match(regExp)
}
```

Even if I hard code the check it still returns null:

```
const string = 'ACG12212'
console.log(string.match(regExp)
```

Comment: Try this: `regExp = /\b[A][A-Z]{2}[0-2]{5}\b/g`

Comment: @anubhava still no match

Comment: Try using \\b.  You may need to backslash the backslash.

Comment: @FrankYellin that was my problem. Now it works as expected. Create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Martheli.  Thanks.  Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\\b`, since so that a single backslash will make through into the string.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the last boundary you have because I think your words may or may not have spaces in between and that might be causing it to be null, try with below.

```js
value = 'asdasADB12210asd'
const regExp = new RegExp('[A][A-Z]{2}[0-2]{5}', 'g')
console.log(value.match(regExp))
```

Comment: That works but I don't want it to return on your example value. If there are other characters or numbers around the value then it should not match. So for example, `ACG12212` should match but `00000ACG122120000` should not.

Comment: You can use negative lookbehind (?<!\d)[A][A-Z]{2}[0-2]{5} and also negative lookahead according to your requirement.